# is it possible to do a dynamic variable inside the data: {} in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

i have this code here

```
(function(Vue,Helper){
var Funds = new Vue({
    el: "#regularFunds",
    data: {
        dynamic data here
        ---example output--
        site: "",
        code: ""
    }
});
```

so how would you put the object data (from database) there?

object = {data1, data2, data3}

how am i suppose to put these in data looking like this: data: { data1: " ", data2: " ", data3: " " }

Comment: data can be function `data: () => { ...dynamic data... }` or use `this.$set`

Comment: you'd add data via https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: It is popular to use axios to fetch data in vue: [example](https://jsfiddle.net/8b34rawv/)

Comment: what i meant was this:
object = {data1, data2, data3} how am i suppose to put these in data looking like this:
 data: {
   data1: " ",
   data2: " ",
   data3: " "
}

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Jiel were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

i solved it with this:

```
mounted: {
    response = {data1: "sample1", data2: "sample2", data3: "sample3"};
    Object.assign(this, response);
}
```

i appreciated your ideas guys..

Comment: i tried this v-model="data1" and it displayed here in my local but in js fiddle its not working so i guess this won't do either

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have this, an you want to put any structure inside the vue declaration, you may want to use the spread operator to do so:

```
window.anyvar = {site: "string",code: "other string"}

(function(Vue,Helper){
var Funds = new Vue({
    el: "#regularFunds",
    data: {...window.anyvar}
});
```

this will get you the object structure of anyvar inside this vue data.

A working Example
https://codepen.io/Teobis/pen/MXrNpV?editors=0012

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

you cannot load data in initial object. you have get mount methods and assign data in initial (define attribute)

```
data: {
    // variable
   dynamicData:[]
}
mounted:function() {
    this.loadData()
},
methods:{
    loadData() {
     // you can load data from here and assign response in to variable
        this.dynamicData = response
    }
}
```

example https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vuejs-dynamic-data

Comment: what i wanted was the variable to be dynamic. :(